# can't execute bash command via c standard system function

Tags: c

the code snippet I wrote is like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  system("/bin/bash ls");
}
```

when I compile and execute the binary, I got the result:
**/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file**

so what's the thing missing here?

Comment: Have you tried without the path?
    system("ls");

Answer (score 5):

`ls` is an actual system binary. it's not a built-in shell command. All you need is `system("ls")`. Right now you're trying to pass the contents of the `ls` binary file into bash as a script.

Comment: @sidyll: uh, why? `echo 'Hi'` and `echo "Hi"` are functionally identical. There's no variables in the command, so...?

Comment: ah man... this is what I get for 2 hours sleep. sorry, you're right.

Comment: No problems ;-) We can delete these comments if you want

Comment: @Marc: if the command I need execute via system is like "/bin/bash unknown", then how can I know the unknown is a binary or a bash buit-in? maybe I can execute which to test the unknown, but are there better ways?

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `system()` from a program , because strange values for some environment variables might be used to subvert system integrity. Use the `exec(3)` family of functions instead, but not execlp(3) or execvp(3). system() will not, in fact, work properly from programs with set-user-ID or set-group-ID privileges on systems on which `/bin/sh is bash version 2`, since bash 2 drops privileges on `startup`. (Debian uses a modified bash which does not do this when invoked as sh.)

In your case , `ls` is not built in command in shell so `system()` is not working.

You can check using `type <cmd_name>` command to know that `cmd_name` is built-in or not.

For more [man system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)

Answer (score 2):

If no options are specified, the argument to /bin/bash is the name of a file containing shell commands to execute.

To execute commands specified on the command line, use the `-c` option: `/bin/bash -c ls`.

As others have noted, there are security considerations when doing this, so you should seek alternatives.